# Problem with view of OpenLayers plugin map and Swiss national coordinate system in print composer

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, print-composer, qgis-openlayers-plugin

My projects are in the Swiss coordinate system (CH0193+ / LV95) and I use OpenLayers Plugin for the base map (Google streets).  In the normal window, this seems to work fine:

[image]

As soon as I open print composer and export the map as PDF, this happens:[image]

As you can see, vectors and map are not congruent any more.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this?

I'd prefer a solution without changing the whole grid, because all the data I am given is this Swiss format.